# jQuery.toggle() extremely slow on many <TR> elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="a"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="b"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

There are nearly 800 rows and most of them of class a. Now I want to toggle these rows like this:

```
    $("#toggle_a").click(function(){
        $("tr.a").toggle();
    });
    $("#toggle_b").click(function(){
        $("tr.b").toggle();
    });
```

But this is really extremely slow and most of the time the browser wants to stop the action.

Has anybody an idea how to make this thing faster and usable?

Answer (score 3):

Seems because jquery searching element by class name..

> Note: The class selector is among the
>   slowest selectors in jQuery; in IE it
>   loops through the entire DOM. Avoid
>   using it whenever possible.

Also check [this](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#use-tags-before-classes) article

Comment: This isn't the issue really, it's the reflow of the table :)

Comment: yea I know, but how to call multiple rows instead of classes?

Comment: you can use each statement, and bind click once document.ready. But some expirienced guys suggest replace table.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but with few lines, about 200.

I used .hide() and .show() and now this almost instantaneous.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, and allowed me to avoid having to change away from a table layout (it is tabular data).

Comment: Worked great for me too. I guess toggle() uses much more processing that a simple switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use tables if you are not displaying tabular data.

Browsers are notoriously slow when you have very large tables (due to the complexity in rendering tables). And there would be quite a lot of reflow happening with this kind of change.

Comment: actually I'm using real tabular data, so there is no workaround

Comment: @adenk - Consider smaller tables. 800 rows are not user friendly, perhaps a more dynamic approach would help. Showing 40 rows at a time, add paging, perhaps use AJAX to populate the table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using table structure, use the LI tag. It will speedy the html render process.

```
<UL style="padding: 0; list-style-type: none;">
    <LI class="a">1</LI>
    <LI class="b">2</LI>
    <LI>3</LI>
    <LI>4</LI>
</UL>
```

Now you can write the selector on this. This will definitely be an improvement